# Ubuntu full upgrade errors, how can I solve these?

Tags: grub2, upgrade, dpkg

Errors were encountered while processing:

r-cran-class

r-cran-kernsmooth

r-cran-nnet

ufw

grub-efi-amd64

grub-efi-amd64-signed

unattended-upgrades

shim-signed

gdm3

ubuntu-desktop

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: You start the process of solving them by showing us the complete, unedited terminal  session. Unfortunately, the summary has no useful information to work with.